# XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation

I am getting XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type error. Even I have added apache poi dependency into pom.xml file. Please help me.

package files;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ReadingExcel {

```
static WebDriver driver;
public void ReadingDataFromExcel() throws FileNotFoundException {
    driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    FileInputStream file= new FileInputStream("E:\\Dev\\Eclipse-workspace\\Data.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook= new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheet= workbook.getSheet("sheet1");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

This is the pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>MySeleniumExercise</groupId>
 <artifactId>MySeleniumExercise</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <name>MySeleniumExercise</name>
 <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
 <url>http://www.example.com</url>

 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.11</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   
   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
   <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
   <version>4.8.1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.3</version>
</dependency>


 </dependencies>

 <build>
   <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
     <plugins>
       <!-- clean lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#clean_Lifecycle -->
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.1.0</version>
       </plugin>
       <!-- default lifecycle, jar packaging: see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.8.0</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.22.1</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.5.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.8.2</version>
       </plugin>
       <!-- site lifecycle, see https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/lifecycles.html#site_Lifecycle -->
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.7.1</version>
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.0</version>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
 </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

XSSFWorkbook is a class under Apache POI framework.
You need to include Apache POI dependencies in you pom.xml file like below:

> ```
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>       <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
>       <version>5.2.2</version>
>   </dependency>
>
>   <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
>   <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
>       <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
>       <version>5.2.2</version>
>   </dependency>
> ```

Then import required classes as below:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivek. You just saved me.

Comment: No Problem, Kindly Voteup